# Where are mailboxes in Gilneas?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've started a Worgen character and have mailed him a handful of useful bits and pieces (heirlooms and other low level gear).  However I haven't been able to find a mailbox in the Gilneas area since I was Level 1 in Gilneas City.  I've reached Stormglen Village and was wondering when am I next likely to see a mailbox?

Comment: You can always set your minimap radar to show mailboxes in your area, but this will only show them in your general vicinity.

Comment: Yes.  The problem is that there appears to be no mailboxes in Gilneas, hence my curiousity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any. You'll see your first mailboxes (and flight points) when you leave that zone. The reason will make sense when you finish the zone quests...

Comment: It makes sense from a lore reason, too... after all, the Wall of Gilnaes was erected to prevent anything outside from entering.  What *doesn't* make sense is why Goblins have mailboxes in their second zone (or so I recall).

Comment: I dispute that it makes sense now that I've finished the zone quests.  I can't see why Gilneas has mailboxes and none of the other small towns do.  Any reason that applies to the latter should also apply to the former.  Alas, that's the way it currently is.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly when this was added (likely patch 4.0.6), but there is now a mailbox in the starting square in Gilnaes.

If you turn around, it should be just past (and to the right of) Gwen Armstead, who gives you the quest Salvage the Supplies.

I'm not sure if any others were added or not.

Comment: I should note that I said 4.0.6 because it was present a month ago when I started a new Worgen.

Comment: That's always been there.  I believe that's the one I was referring to that I saw back in Gilneas City.

Answer (score 4):

There IS a mailbox in Gilneas, near Duskhaven, just outside the Inn.

Answer (score 1):

I found one. If you run back into the city, in the Merchant Square that was the starting area, the mailbox is still there. Depending at what point in your questing you do this, however, the city might have forsaken crawling in it. For me, I was at the quest where you rescue the miners when I decided I really hated the toon and wanted to send off my looms.

Up until you trigger the forsaken to swarm the city (which I think isn't until you're on the quest to retake it), you can run back into the Merchant Square and use the mailbox.

Comment: If you run back to the Merchant Square it is no longer there. I just did but the town is deserted and you can see nothing. :( I'm forced to finish all the damn quests to delete this toon and get my heirlooms back.